# Why does an intersection prevent setting a value that accepts any type to a string?

Tags: typescript

```js
type DataSet<T> = Partial<Record<keyof T, any>> & { properties?: any };

abstract class Data<T> {
  data: DataSet<T> = {};

  set(key: keyof T, value: string) {
    this.data[key] = value;
  } ˜˜˜˜˜˜˜˜˜˜˜˜˜˜
}
```

This gives the following error:

> Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'DataSet[keyof T]'.

The error can be resolved by:

1. Removing the intersection `& { properties?: any }` (however, I need to keep this), or
2. Typecasting value `as any` or setting its type in the method declaration to `any`, both of which seem sloppy as I am expecting a string (and my actual implementation is much more complex than this example).

Are these the only ways to resolve this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you start using mapped and conditional types with unresolved type parameters typescript can't always follow the logic of the types through them. In this case it seems the intersection is tripping things up, and the compiler gives up on figuring that the type of all properties is any.

You can use a type assertion:

```
type DataSet<T> = Partial<Record<keyof T, any>> & { properties?: any };

abstract class Data<T> {
  data: DataSet<T> = {};

  set(key: keyof T, value: string) {
    this.data[key] = value as DataSet<T>[keyof T];
  } 
}
```

Or if all properties are `any` you could simplify the type a little to add the extra property in the mapped type instead of using an intersection. This will let the compiler figure out that all properties are `any`:

```
type DataSet<T> = Partial<Record<keyof T | "properties", any>>

abstract class Data<T> {
  data: DataSet<T> = {};

  set(key: keyof T, value: string) {
    this.data[key] = value;
  } 
}
```

[play](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=9&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAIghsOBlCwA8AVAfFAvFABTgCdgBLOAGzQCUIBjAe2IBM0BrCERgMygygAfKACIwxRpFJkIAZxEAaKHAB2ILFgBQmuACNZwYnHrAo9SnFmzYCOJhwBvTVCgtbALhuIU6bHigOAL4A3NousqgAFJwgnjG8-EoAblQArhCeBsRkKgDmAJQBzi5QwAAWZLIAdG6IANoxALr+KZTpoS6BUJqBQA)

Comment: Shouldn't be *set* method typed like this: set(key: keyof DataSet<T>, value: string). Otherwise it doesn't include *properties* key.

Comment: @SciFiThief That is an interesting point, not sure what intention is here.

Comment: I don't want the properties key to be settable via `set()`. If the dev attempts to do so, I'd like TypeScript to warn them not to. In my own implementation, this is much more explicit. But I tried to be brief, here.

Comment: This answer also made me realize that DataSet<T & { properties?: any }> also works, which provides the flexibility I need in my actual implementation. +1